# How to update an object after expiry date reached? Express / Typeorm / Type-Graphql

Tags: express, typeorm, typegraphql

Ideally:

1. User creates object, which has an expiry date set 24 hours in the future.
2. After 24 hours, the object in the database is updated. EXPIRED field set to true.

The number of objects would be 10000+.
The website traffic is evenly distributed throughout the day.

Currently using Typegraphql, Typeorm w/ Express.

Not sure what the best practice is when doing something like this, or even where to look for answers (can't seem to search the right questions).

Answer (score 1):

For this task I usually use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron. It run code at the moment you need.